# Save json string to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, json

The JSONObject format string below stored inside the arraylist  ArrayListlatestNews;

response.toString() is

```
{
    "blue": [
        {
            "title": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "info": " http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "link": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "image": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "pubDate": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "guid": "http:\\www.b"
        }
    ]
}{
    "blue": [
        {
            "title": "http"
        },
        {
            "info": " 5449 1616"
        },
        {
            "link": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "image": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "pubDate": "Thu, 26 Jun 2014 16:25:25 GMT"
        },
        {
            "guid": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "title": "Weekend"
        },
        {
            "info": " 3345 4353"
        },
        {
            "link": "http:\\www.b.."
        },
        {
            "image": "http:\\www.b..."
        },
        {
            "pubDate": "Mon, 23 Jun 2014 09:47:25 GMT"
        },
        {
            "guid": "http:\\www.b"
        }
    ]
}{
    "blue": [
        {
            "title": "KARAVAN "
        },
        {
            "info": " 4444444"
        },
        {
            "link": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "image": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "pubDate": "Thu, 26 Jun 2014 16:25:25 GMT"
        },
        {
            "guid": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "title": "IMC "
        },
        {
            "info": " 134 3333"
        },
        {
            "link": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "image": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "pubDate": "Mon, 23 Jun 2014 09:47:25 GMT"
        },
        {
            "guid": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "title": "property "
        },
        {
            "info": " 633 1352 \ 537 18211"
        },
        {
            "link": "http:\\www....l"
        },
        {
            "image": "http:\\www...."
        },
        {
            "pubDate": "Thu, 26 Jun 2014 16:09:01 GMT"
        },
        {
            "guid": "http:\\www...."
        }
  ....
```

LatestNews.class

```
public class LatestNews {

    public String title;
    public String info;
    public String link;
    public String image;
    public String pubDate;
    public String guid;

    public LatestNews (String title_,String info_,String link_,String image_,String pubDate_,String guid_){

        this.title=title_;
        this.info=info_;
        this.link=link_;
        this.image=image_;
        this.pubDate=pubDate_;
        this.guid=guid_;

    }

}
```

I am extracting the json as follows

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                 JSONArray venues = obj.getJSONArray("blue");
                System.out.println("response object "+venues.length());

                for (int x=0;x<venues.length();x++){
                    JSONObject keyValue = venues.getJSONObject(x);

                    if (keyValue.has("title")){
                        System.out.println("xxxtitle "+keyValue.getString("title"));

                    }

                }
```

But when i print keyValue.getString("title") only the first title is printed. How can i print all elements from each blue object and before saving it to an arraylist. any help welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First and for most, your JSON response isn't as per the standard and Optimized one.

Implement your web service logic to get response in below format, it would help you to reduce parsing logic/code and iterations too, which would help you to improve app performance too.

```
{
    "blue": [
        {
            "title": "http:\\www.b",
            "info": " http:\\www.b",
            "link": "http:\\www.b",
            "image": "http:\\www.b",
            "pubDate": "http:\\www.b",
            "guid": "http:\\www.b"
        },
        {
            "title": "http:\\www.b",
            "info": " http:\\www.b",
            "link": "http:\\www.b",
            "image": "http:\\www.b",
            "pubDate": "http:\\www.b",
            "guid": "http:\\www.b"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now regarding JSON parsing tutorials/code, there are plenty of examples available on the web and on Stackoverflow too, here you go: [JSON Parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20JSON%20parsing)

**Mistakes in your code and JSON format/logic:**
As you said only first title is getting printed, reason behind for that is you have written `obj.getJSONArray("blue");` which would give you first 'blue' object only and so it will give you a title value from the blue object.

I have already suggest an optimized solution above!

Comment: @blackbelt nope it should not as I am updating answer with more detail. I am already aware about rules. Thanks Though :)

Comment: I am aware that you are aware about the rules.. Anyway if the problem was a malformed JSON, the object's creation would have failed, I think..

Comment: @blackbelt theres no way the above answer would fit in a comment

Comment: @blackbelt just check updated answer with **mistakes** detail.